# SymPy Wronskian function

Tags: function, math, jupyter-notebook, linear-algebra, determinants

I have been trying to compute the wronskian using SymPy, and can not figure out how to use the function. I did look at the program itself but I am very new to python. For functions any sinusoidal is okay. I just want to observe how to use SymPy in this way for future reference. Any help would be great! [image]

~I listed my imports below

```
import sympy as sp
from scipy import linalg
import numpy as np
sp.init_printing()
```

[image]

I don't this that 'var' is the only thing wrong with what I am inputting.

Comment: Please show your full code ..until the error starts .especially the function for which you wish to derive derivatives for Wronskian. Also include full error trace. Don't paste images instead paste as text

Comment: The functions are missing in the call to sp.matrices.dense.wronskian .. you have to pass a list of functions as the first argument

Comment: I will update it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the var first. You have not defined it. Also the functions should go in a list.

```py
x = sp.Symbol('x')
## Define your var here
Wronskian_Sol = sp.matrices.dense.wronskian([sp.sin(x), 1-sp.cos(x)**2], var, method="bareiss")
```

Here is an example in [this book "Applied Differntial Equation with Boundary Value Problems" by Vladimir A. Dobrushkin](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=isVQDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) at page 199.
I computed a Wronskian for these three functions using Sympy

- x
- x*sin(x)
- x*cons(x)

```py
import sympy as sp
x = sp.Symbol('x')
var = x
Wronskian_Sol = sp.matrices.dense.wronskian([x, x*sp.cos(x), x*sp.sin(x)], var, method="bareiss")
print(Wronskian_Sol)
print(Wronskian_Sol.simplify())
```

This gives the output. The first is not simplified, the last one is simplified. You can reduce the first one to simplified version easily by taking the common factor x**3 out which leaves (sin(x)**2 + cos(x)**2) ..and this is nothing but 1.

```py
x**3*sin(x)**2 + x**3*cos(x)**2
x**3
```

You can confirm the solution by manually taking the determinant of the derivative matrix.